# How to group all the nodes on the basis of attribute using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have got below given XML output:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <navigation path="/english">
      <resources>
        <Copyright>© 2009 mysite. All Rights Reserved.</Copyright>
      </resources>
      <node title="010. Terms and Conditions" id="tcm:233-242834-64" url="termscondition.aspx" compTitle="Terms and Conditions"/>
        <node title="Root" id="tcm:233-38288-4" url="/">
            <node title="040. Skywards" id="tcm:233-38448-4" url="/Skywards/skywards.aspx" indexpage="tcm:233-192262-64" compTitle="Skywards" imageSrcOn="/english/Images/skywards_on_tcm233-191728.gif" imageSrcOff="/english/Images/skywards_off_tcm233-191727.gif" imageSrcSelected="/english/Images/skywards_sel_tcm233-191730.gif" imageSrcSelectedOn="/english/Images/skywards_on2_tcm233-191729.gif" accessKey="S" Group="SB">   
                <node title="010. Membership Tiers" id="tcm:481-38882-4" url="/Skywards/membership_tiers/membership_tiers.aspx" indexpage="tcm:481-194317-64" compTitle="Membership Tiers"/>
                <node title="020. Earning Miles" id="tcm:481-38883-4" url="/Skywards/earning_miles/earning_miles.aspx" indexpage="tcm:481-194318-64" compTitle="Earning Skywards Miles"/>
                <node title="030. Travel Rewards" id="tcm:481-38884-4" url="/Skywards/travel_rewards/travel_rewards.aspx" indexpage="tcm:481-194320-64" compTitle="Travel Rewards"/>                 
            </node>
            <node title="H030. Search" id="tcm:233-38483-4" url="/search/search.aspx" indexpage="tcm:233-214259-64" compTitle="Search" localTitle="Search" accessKey="3" Group="SB"/>
            <node title="H010. Homepage" id="tcm:233-192367-64" url="/index.aspx" localTitle="Home" accessKey="0" Group="Home"/>
            <node title="H020. Skyward Homepage" id="tcm:233-143367-64" url="/index.aspx" localTitle="Home" accessKey="0" Group="Home"/>
        </node>
        <node title="footer">
            <node title="F010. 000. Sitemap" id="tcm:233-192374-64" url="/sitetools/sitemap.aspx" accessKey="4" compTitle="Sitemap"/>
            <node title="F060. Accessibility" id="tcm:233-192369-64" url="/sitetools/accessibility.aspx" compTitle="Accessibility Statement"/>
            <node title="F030. Operational Updates" id="tcm:233-192370-64" url="/sitetools/operational_updates.aspx" compTitle="Operational Updates"/>
            <node title="F050. Privacy Policy" id="tcm:233-192371-64" url="/sitetools/privacy_policy.aspx" compTitle="Privacy Policy"/>
            <node title="F040. Terms &amp; Conditions" id="tcm:233-192449-64" url="/sitetools/terms_and_conditions.aspx" compTitle="Terms &amp; Conditions"/>
        </node>
    </navigation>
```

Now want to write an xslt which will group the nodes on the basis of attribute "Group" with their value and add them in seperate node so that my ouput will be as given below:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<navigation path="/english">
  <resources>
    <Copyright>© 2009 mysite. All Rights Reserved.</Copyright>
  </resources>
  <node title="010. Terms and Conditions" id="tcm:233-242834-64" url="termscondition.aspx" compTitle="Terms and Conditions"/>
    <node title="Root" id="tcm:233-38288-4" url="/">
        <node title="040. Skywards" id="tcm:233-38448-4" url="/Skywards/skywards.aspx" indexpage="tcm:233-192262-64" compTitle="Skywards" imageSrcOn="/english/Images/skywards_on_tcm233-191728.gif" imageSrcOff="/english/Images/skywards_off_tcm233-191727.gif" imageSrcSelected="/english/Images/skywards_sel_tcm233-191730.gif" imageSrcSelectedOn="/english/Images/skywards_on2_tcm233-191729.gif" accessKey="S" Group="SB">   
        </node>
        <node title="H030. Search" id="tcm:233-38483-4" url="/search/search.aspx" indexpage="tcm:233-214259-64" compTitle="Search" localTitle="Search" accessKey="3" Group="SB"/>
        <node title="H010. Homepage" id="tcm:233-192367-64" url="/index.aspx" localTitle="Home" accessKey="0" Group="Home"/>
        <node title="H020. Skyward Homepage" id="tcm:233-143367-64" url="/index.aspx" localTitle="Home" accessKey="0" Group="Home"/>
    </node>
    <node title="footer">
        <node title="F010. 000. Sitemap" id="tcm:233-192374-64" url="/sitetools/sitemap.aspx" accessKey="4" compTitle="Sitemap"/>
        <node title="F060. Accessibility" id="tcm:233-192369-64" url="/sitetools/accessibility.aspx" compTitle="Accessibility Statement"/>
        <node title="F030. Operational Updates" id="tcm:233-192370-64" url="/sitetools/operational_updates.aspx" compTitle="Operational Updates"/>
        <node title="F050. Privacy Policy" id="tcm:233-192371-64" url="/sitetools/privacy_policy.aspx" compTitle="Privacy Policy"/>
        <node title="F040. Terms &amp; Conditions" id="tcm:233-192449-64" url="/sitetools/terms_and_conditions.aspx" compTitle="Terms &amp; Conditions"/>
    </node>
    <node GroupTitle="SB">
        <nodes>
            <node title="040. Skywards" id="tcm:233-38448-4" url="/Skywards/skywards.aspx" indexpage="tcm:233-192262-64" compTitle="Skywards" imageSrcOn="/english/Images/skywards_on_tcm233-191728.gif" imageSrcOff="/english/Images/skywards_off_tcm233-191727.gif" imageSrcSelected="/english/Images/skywards_sel_tcm233-191730.gif" imageSrcSelectedOn="/english/Images/skywards_on2_tcm233-191729.gif" accessKey="S" Group="SB">   
            </node>
            <node title="H030. Search" id="tcm:233-38483-4" url="/search/search.aspx" indexpage="tcm:233-214259-64" compTitle="Search" localTitle="Search" accessKey="3" Group="SB"/>
        </nodes> 
    </node>   
    <node GroupTitle="Home">
        <nodes>
            <node title="H010. Homepage" id="tcm:233-192367-64" url="/index.aspx" localTitle="Home" accessKey="0" Group="Home"/>
            <node title="H020. Skyward Homepage" id="tcm:233-143367-64" url="/index.aspx" localTitle="Home" accessKey="0" Group="Home"/>
        </nodes> 
    </node>     
</navigation>
```

Please suggest!!

Comment: @_Manu: Your code/data is unuunderstandable, because it has very long lines that require horizontal scrolling all the time. Please, edit and format for readability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This stylesheet should do the trick:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <!-- Key for Group attributes -->
    <xsl:key name="nodesByGroups" match="node[@Group]" use="@Group" />

    <xsl:template match="/*">

        <!-- Making shallow copy of root element -->
        <xsl:copy>

            <!-- Making deep copy of all child elements, as well as any root element attributes -->
            <xsl:copy-of select="*|@*" />

            <!-- Calling the template for grouping on the root element -->
            <xsl:call-template name="group" />

        </xsl:copy>

    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="group">

        <!-- Apply the technique known as Muenchian grouping -->
        <xsl:for-each select="//node[generate-id() = generate-id(key('nodesByGroups', @Group)[1])]/@Group">
            <xsl:variable name="group" select="." />
            <xsl:element name="node">
                <xsl:attribute name="GroupTitle"><xsl:value-of select="$group" /></xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:element name="nodes">
                    <xsl:copy-of select="/*//node[@Group = $group]" />
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:for-each>

    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The second template makes use of a technique known as [Muenchian grouping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muenchian_grouping). It can be a little complex at first to understand should you not be familiar with XSLT and XPath, but once you get it, it becomes a great tool. There's a thorough explanation of it [here](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html).

EDIT: you could write the second template like this, if you find it more legible:

```
<xsl:template name="group">

    <!-- Apply the technique known as Muenchian grouping -->
    <xsl:for-each select="//node[generate-id() = generate-id(key('nodesByGroups', @Group)[1])]/@Group">
        <xsl:variable name="group" select="." />
        <node GroupTitle="{$group}">
            <nodes>
                <xsl:copy-of select="/*//node[@Group = $group]" />
            </nodes>
        </node>
    </xsl:for-each>

</xsl:template>
```

**EDIT 2**: okay, I hope this will do what you need:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <!-- Key for Group attributes -->
    <xsl:key name="nodesByGroups" match="node[@Group]" use="@Group" />

    <xsl:template match="/*">

        <!-- Making shallow copy of root element -->
        <xsl:copy>

            <!-- Apply templates on all the child elements/attributes as appropriate -->
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />

            <!-- Calling the template for grouping on the root element -->
            <xsl:call-template name="group" />

        </xsl:copy>

    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="node">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="node[@Group]">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="group">

        <!-- Apply the technique known as Muenchian grouping -->
        <xsl:for-each select="//node[generate-id() = generate-id(key('nodesByGroups', @Group)[1])]/@Group">
            <xsl:variable name="group" select="." />
            <xsl:element name="node">
                <xsl:attribute name="GroupTitle"><xsl:value-of select="$group" /></xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:element name="nodes">
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="/*//node[@Group = $group]" />
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:for-each>

    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, I just need the current node to be added in the new Grouping node, not whole child node as well, above code is grouping very well, however only one issue is that it is copying all the child node as well. please suggest!!

Comment: @Manu The stylesheet I provided results in exactly the output you've shown in your post, when I use your sample XML. If you require different output, please edit your post to show us what the output should be precisely.

Comment: I have edited the question, Now your code above works fine, its grouping perfectly as required, only issue is that it is copying all the child nodes as well, so in above case if you see "040. Skywards" has got attribute Group="SB" its getting grouped perfectly but its child nodes are also added below, now I want only the parent nodes to be in the grouping not the child nodes. Please suggest!!